# Почему клавиатура на андроид перекрывает контент, а ios- нет?

Tags: html, jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Столкнулся с проблемой, никак не могу решить.
есть форма с position:fixed. При нажатии на поле формы, на андроид клавиатура перекрывает его, но на ios- сдвигает вверх вместе с содержимым. Есть ли решение для андроид?

[image: Android]

[image: IOS]

Comment: Есть мнение, что платформы тут не причем. Все зависит от конкретного браузера.

Comment: учесть при верстке сайта это можно?